# Scatter plot in plotly is not showing all data points

Tags: pandas, plot, plotly-dash

I am new to data science and I am doing some data visualization analysis with plotly dash, but I've tried different way to arrange x & y, but the graph doesn't plot all the data points.

The sample data x has 70 columns with binary data of 0 & 1, and y has data of 1, 2, 3. They are all categorical data after pandas.get_dummies treatment

Can anyone please advice? Thanks in advance!!

```
import numpy as np 
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
arr_x=np.array(df2.drop("Severity_Level",1).values)
arr_y=np.array(df2["Severity_Level"].values)

data = [go.Scatter(x=arr_x, 
                   y=arr_y, 
                   mode='markers',
                  marker= dict(
                      size=12,
                      color='rgb(51,98,30)',
                      symbol = 'pentagon',
                      line = {'width':2}
                  ))]

layout = go.Layout(title= 'Severity Level Plot',
                  xaxis={'title':'project data'},
                  yaxis=dict(title='y-axis'), ## Dic is when you want to pass title, color... like the marker above
                  hovermode='closest')

fig = go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)

pyo.plot(fig, filename='scatter.html')
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is missing the part that actually builds `df2`. What are its contents?

Comment: right, df2 has 71 columns with binary data. How do I have the df2 data points in the chart?

Comment: have you checked the datatype of the data that you want to plot?